# VirtualBox start error on macOS 10.12.4

Tags: virtualbox, macos-sierra

Failed to acquire the VirtualBox COM object.

The application will now terminate.

Callee RC: NS_ERROR_ABORT (0x80004004)

I tried from 5.1.10 to 5.1.22, but got the same error above.

Answer (score 7):

resolved by uninstall it first and install again. NOT install it by overwite.

Comment: It does work on macOS 10.12.4, VirtualBox 5.1.22

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Ran this as administrator:

```
cd /tmp
sudo rm -rf .vbox-<your user>-ipc
```

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: Does not work on 10.13.6 (17G65)

Comment: Does not work on macOS 10.12.6 and VirtualBox 5.2.18

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to run the [uninstaller tool](https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Installer/darwin/DiskImage/VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool) provided with an earlier version (4.3.14 or something) of VirtualBox.